# What's the easiest way to make swift crash?

Tags: swift, crash

I would like to make swift crash, to test some crash handling functionality of my app.

In C++ I usually dereference a *NULL* pointer to do that, like so:

```
int *i = 0;
*i = 42;
```

What the easiest way to generate a crash in swift?

Comment: Force unwrapping a optional

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the forced unwrapping operator on a nil optional variable:

```
let number: Int? = nil
let val = number!
```

That should throw an exception like this:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

However you can also use a more elegant way to make your app crash, using the `fatalError` global function, which stops the program execution - but it accepts some parameters that can be useful depending on what you are trying to achieve:

```
@noreturn func fatalError(@autoclosure message: () -> String = default, file: StaticString = default, line: UWord = default)
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I found another way myself (although I'm not sure if it's iOS specific).

Simply calling *abort* will do the job:

```
abort()
```

Answer (score 3):

One more easy way to make swift crash:

```
let testArray = ["1","2","3"]
let a = testArray[4]
```

That will throw an exception like this:

> fatal error: Array index out of range

because you are trying to access member of array which is not present at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add fatalError() in your code.

```
fatalError()
```